# Fazer Split da string que está entre duas \

Tags: java, string, regex, split

Estou tentando fazer o split por `\` da string abaixo, queria pegar apenas `Yorktown`, mas não estou conseguindo.

```
\Locations\North America\US Mid-Hudson Valley\Yorktown\Yorktown Heights\
```

Meu código está assim:

```
String[] locationCategory1 = row.getCell(0).getStringCellValue().split("/[\\.]/");
             String locationCategory1splited = locationCategory1[4];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Algumas linguagens exigem que uma regex esteja entre delimitadores, sendo a `/` o mais comum. Mas **não** é o caso do Java, você não precisa colocar as barras no início e fim. Ao colocá-las, o `split` tentará procurar pelo próprio caractere `/`.

Outro detalhe é que `[\\.]` na verdade corresponde ao caractere `.`, então sua regex está buscando por uma barra, seguida de ponto, seguida de outra barra.

Se a ideia é separar por `\`, basta colocar este caractere. Um detalhe chato é que ele é usado em regex para fazer o escape de meta caracteres e para que ele seja interpretado como o próprio caractere `\`, você precisa escrevê-lo como `\\`.

Só que em uma string do Java, `"\\"` resulta em apenas um `\`, então a regex tem que ser escrita como `\\\\` (isso se transforma na regex `\\`, que corresponde ao caractere `\`). Assim:

```
String s = "\\Locations\\North America\\US Mid-Hudson Valley\\Yorktown\\Yorktown Heights\\";
System.out.println(s.split("\\\\")[4]);
```

A saída do código acima é "Yorktown".

Comment: Muito obrigada! Funcionou!!

Comment: hkotsubo rei das regex